# python-rq: worker is busy but current_job doesn't exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-rq

I'm using [python-rq](https://python-rq.org/) to enqueue background tasks and then attempting to check their status in my web app.

First I grab all the workers attached to the queue:

```
 workers = rq.Worker.all(queue=queue)
```

Before starting a task there is a single worker with state `idle` that looks like this:

```
pid : 9
job_class : <class 'rq.job.Job'>
queue_class : <class 'rq.queue.Queue'>
version : 1.4.2
python_version : 3.7.7 (default, Jun  9 2020, 17:58:51) 
[GCC 8.3.0]
serializer : <class 'rq.serializers.DefaultSerializer'>
name : c3482062db0043ddb4ccc3cdeefb027b
queues : [Queue('training_tasks')]
_exc_handlers : []
default_result_ttl : 500
default_worker_ttl : 420
job_monitoring_interval : 30
_state : idle
_is_horse : False
_horse_pid : 0
_stop_requested : False
log : <Logger rq.worker (INFO)>
log_job_description : True
last_cleaned_at : None
successful_job_count : 0
failed_job_count : 0
total_working_time : 0
birth_date : 2020-06-29 15:45:25.704249
scheduler : None
disable_default_exception_handler : False
_job_id : None
last_heartbeat : 2020-06-29 15:45:25.712674
```

After I enqueue a job and it starts to be processed, the work begins and the `state` updates to `busy`.

```
 pid : 9
 job_class : <class 'rq.job.Job'>
 queue_class : <class 'rq.queue.Queue'>
 version : 1.4.2
 python_version : 3.7.7 (default, Jun  9 2020, 17:58:51) 
 [GCC 8.3.0]
 serializer : <class 'rq.serializers.DefaultSerializer'>
 name : c3482062db0043ddb4ccc3cdeefb027b
 queues : [Queue('training_tasks')]
 _exc_handlers : []
 default_result_ttl : 500
 default_worker_ttl : 420
 job_monitoring_interval : 30
 _state : busy
 _is_horse : False
 _horse_pid : 0
 _stop_requested : False
 log : <Logger rq.worker (INFO)>
 log_job_description : True
 last_cleaned_at : None
 successful_job_count : 0
 failed_job_count : 0
 total_working_time : 0
 birth_date : 2020-06-29 15:45:25.704249
 scheduler : None
 disable_default_exception_handler : False
 _job_id : b'a460194c-e0ac-4cc6-8d4d-41c62a2eca41'
 last_heartbeat : 2020-06-29 15:46:47.185807
```

The [docs](https://python-rq.org/docs/workers/#retrieving-worker-information) state that the worker should have a `current_job` property that can be inspected for e.g. meta data, but my workers don't have it. There is a `job_id` that I guess I could use but I'd like to know why my worker doesn't have the properties that the docs say that it should.

(I'm using rq 1.4.2 and redis 3.5.3 running on gunicorn with gevent)